# How to replace single words in language 1 by words in language 2 by using a separate dataframe that contains both languages?

Tags: r, replace, character, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with Spanish words and would like to replace them with their English translations. The translations are save in a separate dictionary dataframe that contains both words. The words in the original dataframe can appear multiple times and in random order. There can also be words in the original dataframe without translation; they should be kept in their original form.

**Source**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(item = c("agua","guerra","pelea","hijo","grande","pelea","agua","guerra"))
dictionary <- tibble(word_ES=c("agua","guerra","pelea"), word_EN=c("water","war","fight"))
```

[image]

**Desired outcome**

```r
df2 <- tibble(item = c("water","war","fight","hijo","grande","fight","water","war"))
```

[image]

I'd be particularly interested in suggestions that use tidyverse packages but am also happy about other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is a join `on` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[setDT(dictionary), item := word_EN, on = .(item = word_ES)]
df
#     item
#1:  water
#2:    war
#3:  fight
#4:   hijo
#5: grande
#6:  fight
#7:  water
#8:    war
```

---

Or if we prefer the `tidyverse`, then do a `left_join` and `coalesce` the output

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   left_join(dictionary, by = c('item' = 'word_ES')) %>% 
   transmute(item = coalesce(word_EN, item))
```

Comment: The second solution is perfect for me and does exactly what I desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in the `tidyverse` using `dplyr` and `stringr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(item = c("agua","guerra","pelea","hijo","grande","pelea","agua","guerra"))
dictionary <- tibble(word_ES=c("agua","guerra","pelea"), word_EN=c("water","war","fight"))

mutate(df, item = str_replace_all(item, setNames(dictionary$word_EN, dictionary$word_ES)))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 1
#>   item  
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 water 
#> 2 war   
#> 3 fight 
#> 4 hijo  
#> 5 grande
#> 6 fight 
#> 7 water 
#> 8 war
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looked perfect for my purpose at first. The only problem is that things go wrong with partial matches. For instance, if you add "pelearse" (verb) to the list, your solution returns "fightrse" (i.e., it replaces "pelea" with "fight" but keeps the additional bit pelea- "rse").